# C++ system function doesn't accept string?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    string kelime="dir";
    system(kelime);
}
```

if i do like this: `char kelime[10]="dir";`

It is working but i want to do it with string? What is the problem, how can I do it?

Comment: Try `system(kelime.c_str());`

Comment: your compiler must be ancient for `string.h` to have `std::string`.

Comment: please do mention the exact error you are getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
system(kelime.c_str());
```

`system()` (and many other APIs) are designed to be called from C, and take so-called C-strings, which are a NUL-terminated array of single-byte ASCII characters.

Use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to get a C string from your C++ `std::string`.

Comment: I did not kno that. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Use `kelime.c_str()` to access the old `char` style